# Docker Migrate from overlay to overlay2

Tags: docker, centos, overlay

By mistake, I have set up a docker daemon running with the overlay driver on centos7.5. Because I have faced issues with the daemon after some time at system reboot, I came to the conclusion that I had to switch to overlay2.

Unfortunately, when switching to overlay2, I loose all existing containers.

Is there a migration path from overlay to overlay2 which recover existing containers?

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this issue doing backup/restore of each running container.